# Definition of continuity for matrix-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, limits, continuity, definition

I'm working on an exercise for analysis:

"In the proof of Theorem 9.3.3 [Chain Rule for functions from $\mathbb R^p$ to $\mathbb R^q$], the following fact is used twice: If $A(h)$ is a $q\times p$ matrix whose entries are functions of $h\in\mathbb R^p$ and if $A(h)$ is continuous at $h=0$, then $\lim_{h\to 0}A(h)h=0$, where $A(h)h$ is the result of the matrix $A(h)$ acting via vector-matrix product on the vector $h$. Prove that this limit is $0$, as claimed,"

and it only just occurred to me that the text had been using the idea of continuous matrix-valued functions without defining it, and so now I'm not sure how to go about proving this fact. I assume the definition would be something like each of the columns or entries being continuous, or the resulting matrix-vector product of the matrix function and some specified vector being continuous, but I want to make sure which.

Comment: Actually these will be equivalent. Take e.g.  continuity of all entries as the definition.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks.

Comment: (The 'specified vector' should range over all vectors, or at least a basis.)

Comment: Good to know! Thanks!

Comment: I strongly suspect that you are mistaken about the text not having defined continuity for matrix valued functions. Perhaps they are simply using the canonical identification of $M(p,q)$ with $\Bbb R^{pq}$.

Comment: They very well might be, but they haven't specified that. If you want to double check it's Taylor's *Foundations of Analysis* (version 2.5). It's also not a particularly good text, in my opinion, but it gets the job done.